# Can't instantiate a class through reflection

Tags: java, reflection

When I user java reflection to create object,It will throw an "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException",this is my code:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("Demo");
        Demo d = (Demo) clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

where I was wrong.

Comment: in which package is `Demo` ?

Comment: org.ejs.demo.createObj

Comment: Then try `Class.forName("org.ejs.demo.createObj.Demo");`

Comment: oh，you are rihgt,the package is must,thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use the fully qualified name of the class, ie including the package, eg:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("com.mycompany.mypackage.Demo");
        Demo d = (Demo) clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass complete package name to `forName` method .

Answer (score 0):

Or, bonus points for a `java.lang.invoke` based solution :)

```
    MethodType mt; MethodHandle mh;
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();

    mt = MethodType.methodType(void.class);

    try {
        Class klass = Class.forName("com.mycompany.mypackage.Demo");
        mh = lookup.findConstructor(klass, mt);

        Object obj = (Object)mh.invoke();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // ERR
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```